# How to simplify $\sum _{l=1} ^{k} \sum_{j_1 \ge 1} \cdots \sum_{j_l \ge 1, j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l} \binom{-2}{l} 2^l$

Tags: binomial-theorem, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to simplify the following equation.

$$\sum _{l=1} ^{k} \sum_{j_1 \ge 1} \cdots \sum_{j_l \ge 1, j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l} \binom{-2}{l} 2^l$$

Or more specifically, I'm solving for the MGF whose moment is defined as follows.

$$M_k = (-1)^k \sum _{l=1} ^{k} \sum_{j_1 \ge 1} \cdots \sum_{j_l \ge 1, j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l} \binom{-2}{l} 2^l$$

I'm stuck in solving it, so I need a hint for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @MarkusScheuer has pointed out, my original answer was incorrect.  I misread  $j_l\ge1$ as $j_1\ge1$ in the subscript.  I think it's right now.

Well to start with, $$\sum _{l=1} ^{k} \sum_{j_1 \ge 1} \cdots \sum_{j_l \ge 1, j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l} \binom{-2}{l} 2^l=\\
\sum _{l=1} ^{k}\binom{-2}{l} 2^l \sum_{j_1 \ge 1} \cdots \sum_{j_l \ge 1, j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l} 
$$
Now we know$$\sum_{ j_1 + \cdots + j_l=k} \binom{k}{j_1 \cdots j_l}=l^k,$$ but we need to exclude the cases where one or more of the summands is $0.$  If some summand is $0$ then the remaining $l-1$ summands add up to $k$, and there are $l$ ways to choose the summand to set to $0,$ so we must subtract $l(l-1)^k.$  However, the cases where two of the summands are $0$ have been subtracted twice, so we have to add back $\binom{l}{2}(l-2)^k$ and so on.  By the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we get 
$$\sum _{l=1} ^{k}\binom{-2}{l} 2^l\sum_{j=0}^l(-1)^j\binom{l}{j}(l-j)^k
$$
The inner sum can be recognized as $$
l!S(k,l)=\sum_{j=0}^l(-1)^j\binom{l}{j}(l-j)^k,
$$
where $S(k,l)={k\brace l}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#A_generalization), described in the wiki article on inclusion-exclusion.  Fortunately, there is a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation) for the Stirling numbers of the second kind, so computing them isn't so bad, at least for reasonably small $k$ and $l$.

So we have $$
\sum _{l=1} ^{k}\binom{-2}{l} 2^l l!{k \brace l}
$$
Now, $$\binom{-2}{l}=\frac{(-2)(-3)\dots(-l-1)}{l!}=\frac{(-1)^l(l+1)!}{l!}=(-1)^l(l+1),$$and we arrive at$$
\sum_{l=1}^k(-2)^l(l+1)!{k \brace l},$$ where ${k\brace l}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

If this can be simplified further, it takes someone more knowledgeable and talented than I am.

Comment: The second equation is valid for $j_i\geq 0$ but here we have $j_i\geq 1$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Yes, that's why I subtracted $(l-1)^k$ at the end.  The case where $j_1=0$ is the case with $l-1$ summands.

Comment: It's not only $j_1$, each of the indices is greater zero.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer You are right!  My eyesight isn't what it used to be, I'm sorry to say.  It may be possible to rescue this, but I'm afraid it will be very complicated.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: I agree. The boundary conditions look rather challenging.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Is it correct now, do you think?

Comment: Ahhh, this looks much more promising. Very nice. (+1)